# jQuery validate - prevent of one word in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, cordova

```
$.validator.addMethod("nok", function(element,value) {
    return !/^\bnok\b$/.test(value);
}, 'Must not be nok!');
// connect it to a css class
$.validator.addClassRules({
    nok : { nok : true }    
});
```

The Problem is: If I trim away the !  at return, I get an validation error every time. No matter if I select ok, nok or not required from the dropdown.
But if I leave the ! at its place, nothing happens. It seems to be valid.

Can anybody help me with this issue and give me an idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed `value` and `element` in the function signature.  Put them in the other order and it will work:

```
$.validator.addMethod("nok", function(value,element) {  /* <-- not element,value */
    return !/^\bnok\b$/.test(value);
}, 'Must not be nok!');
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/83rvd/

Comment: But one more question: How can I check the selected options text instead of the value...? I tried everything (e.g. $(element).text()) but it seems not to work as expected.